# Is there a way to capture & handle "next" and "previous” using Google Actions with Actions SDK as the fulfillment tool When Media Response was sent?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm using the Media Response to play audio in my Actions SDK (Action SDK is being used as the Fulfillment tool in my Actions Console) driven Action. At the end of each audio clip, I'm using the MEDIA_STATUS callback to advance to another mp3 file in a predefined playlist. As a result, users should be able to navigate forwards / backwards.

When testing on my Google Home mini, Google Assistant on Android and Smart Display, I can intercept "next" and advance to the next audio clip (it sends a request with intent of type MEDIA_STATUS). However, I can't properly intercept "previous" Whenever I try, the audio will restart. Real devices seems to be handling this intent on it's own and does not throw any console output (as my webhook is not accessed at all).

Dialog Flow seem to handle "next" and "previous" as follow up intents, but I need to do the same without using Dialog Flow as the Fulfillment tool.

Can anyone please help with this particular problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently only a FINISHED event is supported for the Media Response. So, you would not be able to handle distinguish between next and previous.

Comment: Hi @Leon Nicholls - can you please refer to my answer in this question, as I am left totally confused as you reply seems to totally contradict your musicplayer example guide. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Referring to @Leon Nicholls [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59724251/401713), I am really confused. I followed his [Google Audioplayer tutorial/guide](https://medium.com/google-developers/two-minute-actions-long-running-audio-c2ed9507493a) which links to an [audioplayer template action](https://oneclickactions.appspot.com/musicPlayer)

You can still download it, and if you unzip it, you will see code that is put there specifically to handle previous and next tracks.

Now it appears Leon is saying that it can't handle previous and next by voice (but buttons appear to work).

Here is the sample code below. There are links to tutorial actions in it, but now [all the content has been removed](https://developers.google.com/actions/samples/actions). I simply need blind people to be able to select and play various bit of audio, too long for SSML, which must be navigable (at least next and pause/resume later) may be part of a playlist. How do I achieve this? Suggesting "Media Partner" or "Podcast" is not a solution as neither available in the UK.

```
// Handle the More/Yes/Next intents
app.intent(['More', 'Yes', 'Next'], (conv) => {
  console.log(`More: fallbackCount=${conv.data.fallbackCount}`);
  nextTrack(conv, false);
});

// Handle the Repeat/Previous intent
app.intent(['Repeat', 'Previous'], (conv) => {
  console.log(`Repeat: ${conv.user.storage.track}`);
  nextTrack(conv, false, true);
});


// Select the next track to play from the data
const nextTrack = (conv, intro, backwards) => {
  console.log(`nextTrack: ${conv.user.storage.track}`);
  let track = data[0];
  // Persist the selected track in user storage
  // https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data#save_data_across_conversations
  if (conv.user.storage.track) {
    conv.user.storage.track = parseInt(conv.user.storage.track, 10);
    if (backwards) {
```